# How to implement Doctrine through the sql query with join?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I can not understand how i can implement through Doctrine such a simple sql query like this :

```
select bt.field
from base_table bt
join joined_table jt on (jt.id = bt.joined_table_id)  
where
  jt.field = 'XXX'
```

Comment: Please post in English only.

Comment: ok. i try to translate it

Answer (score 2):

Supposing you're in the `base_table`s entity repository and having the two table's entity mapping correctly set:

```
public function getBaseTableFields()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('bt')
        ->select('bt.field')
        ->innerJoin('bt.joined_table', 'jt')
        ->where('jt.field = :fieldValue')
        ->setParameter('fieldValue', 'XXX')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

But I suggest you to read the [symfony doctrine docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html)